# Pages missing in Gromov: Rigid transformations groups

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, paper-request

I cannot find a complete version of the 1988 paper *Rigid transformations groups* by Gromov. The only version I can find is the [one on the authors homepage](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/rigid_transformation.pdf). However this version appears to be missing pages 2 and 3 (it starts on page 65 and the next page is 68, among other things the definition of $r$-rigidity is missing).

Is a complete version of the paper available online?

Comment: The paper with Giuseppina d'Ambra has the complete definitions, and more details.